# Oracle Object Types

Tags: oracle, oracle-objects

In my lectures I learnt about **ORACLE OBJECT TYPES** mentioning **COLUMN OBJECT** and **ROW OBJECT**. I don't find enough details in my lectures regarding the object types. I have googled a lot to find at least a article about these object types, but I was unable to find any article which mentions about **COLUMN OBJECT** and **ROW OBJECT**.

This may be a beginner question. Would anyone please explain or provide an article link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this link [Oracle types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm)

And there is a perfect definition:

Row Objects and Column Objects

Objects that are stored in complete rows in object tables are called row objects. Objects that are stored as columns of a table in a larger row, or are attributes of other objects, are called column objects.

In common language, what it means, its naming the "sections" of the object. From left to right - row object, from top to bottom - column object. Nothing more. Focus on the types itself and their structures and practical usages.

Is it more clear now? Or you we need to elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I think I found the one I was looking for

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Good luck on Oracle journey!